# Set the dpi for a figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, figure, dpi

I got a small problem with the dpi of figures, or maybe windows is just trolling me.
I use the following line to print the image

```
fig =gcf;
fig.PaperPositionMode = 'auto';
print('ScreenSizeFigure',-djpeg,'-r600');
```

So this are the statistics of the resulting image according to windows:

- Dimensions: 11900x6169
- Width 11900
- Pixels Height 6169 Pixels
- Horizontal resolution 96 dpi
- Vertical resoltuion 96 dpi

So is something wrong with Matlab (I am using Matlab R2019b Update 6), my code, or is windows just giving me wrong information?
I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0):

This is to some degree a known problem. You might wanna try another Matlab function.
[export_fig.m exports figures nicely to a number of vector & bitmap formats](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig)

Here are some demos:
[https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/blob/master/README.md](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig)

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a single figure, use the GUI of the export-setup.

[image: MATLAB's export setup]

*File > Export Setup ... > Rendering > Resolution (dpi)* + don't forget to click *Apply to Figure*.

It comes handy to define an *Export Style* if you need to export multiple figures with the same size/font/rendering. Once you have one defined, you can load and apply it to your figures automatically with this simple function:

```matlab
function FigExport(fh,FileName,ExpStyl)
%%
ax = get(fh, 'children');
lg = arrayfun(@(x)isa(x,'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes'),ax);
if ~all(cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'on'),{ax(lg).Box}))
    box(ax(lg),'on')
end

% get style sheet info
if nargin < 3 || isempty(ExpStyl)
    ExpStyl = 'PPT'; % The name of your style file (NO extension)
end
s = hgexport('readstyle',ExpStyl);

%% apply style sheet info & export file
if isempty(FileName)
    FileName = 'tmpFigExprt';
end

s.Format = 'jpeg'; %I needed this to make it work but maybe you wont.
hgexport(fh,FileName,s);
end
```